# Professional screencast with audio drawings and quizzes

Tags: sound, software-recommendation, screencast

I want to create some screencasts with audio using Ubuntu.
I also would like to be able to make "drawings", like arrows pointing at
different part of the screen, shade a part of the screen and leave a portion bright.

Optionally I would also like to insert quizzes so that the video can only proceed
when the right answers have been inserted.

This videos should then be uploaded on my website which uses wordpress.

What software/s can I use to do this?

Comment: Quizzes are kind of hard to implement as part of a video file. I'd go for a program that allows everything else, then use Wordpress and PHP to make quizzes between smaller videos.

Comment: I agree with ObsessiveSSOℲ, Take a look at this [Post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/302643/how-to-make-a-screencast-in-13-04/302727#302727)for creating a screencast.

Comment: thanks for the comments :) ObsessiveSSOℲ can you link me to some resource that explains how to use php to create quizzes between the videos? Can I make so that to the user it seems like it is one unique video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Vokoscreen to capture my desktop. For quizzes I use Google Forms and embed both the video and quiz in the blogger platform that I use.

As for drawing or arrows on the screen, that is what led me to this page. It is an unanswered question at this point for me.

Comment: Your answer would be improved if you added information about how you installed Vokoscreen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use youTube. Now YouTube allows you to add the multiple choice questions inside the video. Check this link. http://www.youtube.com/testtube

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.